# Configuration for reverse proxies in a local Docker/Apache/PHP environment

Tags: docker, php

I am refactoring my local environment from MAMP-pro to PHP/apache/Docker.

What is the proper configuration to implement a reverse proxy (in order to maintain the named-url site functionality of MAMP-pro) in this environment without the use of third party tools (IE Caddy server or NGINX)

My goal is to have a bunch of Docker Apache/PHP containers running at once, each running one application that is accessible by a named URL.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: So you want an apache-based reverse proxy?  https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/reverse_proxy.html  https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-apache-http-server-as-reverse-proxy-using-mod_proxy-extension

Comment: @030 things that would work locally, before realizing that adding sites to the hosts file on the container would help at all

Comment: @chicks yup, I do. I read both of those articles, but cannot make either work with docker

Comment: I can't make something from this question, mamp stand for Mac Apache Mysql Php, what are you willing to do in docker? The automatic dns/vhost Config has nothing to do with that, it's scripts/tooling included in mamp you will have to replace but there's no final goal here...

Comment: @Tensibai Mamp does indeed stand for that. Mamp pro is a bit of software that, among other other things, allows for multiple sites to be run locally with custom URLs. I am seeking a way to replicate that: IE run all my sites on docker with those custom local URLs

Comment: I have edited the question to make it more clear

Comment: Use traefik to route them, moving to docker change the paradigm, you'll probably need an orchestration layer like k8s (look for minikube for a dev station) or swarm to tell traefik about the containers running so it can self configure to route to them by hostname

Comment: BTW my remark about mamp is that you're asking in the title for php apache Mac Apache Mysql Php (it's redundant and badly worded, it has been better to drop a word about what mamp is than dropping words   side by side)

Comment: @Tensibai I notice that you are suggesting a third party tool, is there a reason for that? Is there a reason that I cannot do this with apache docker containers?

Comment: You can reinvent the wheel as much as you wish, something will have to ask docker daemon for containers and then write apache vhost configuration to proxy to containers, that's a lot of work and a bunch of people are already doing it in an open source way, I see no reasons to not use it.

Comment: (btw if you put this into an answer with detail I will accept it) Fascinating, I wonder why something that seems so basic isn't already baked in